# Why does using a TSQL variable in a WHERE clause produce different results than using a constant of the same value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I run the following two SQL statements (SQL Server 2008 R2), I get different results. The first excludes rows where pernr is NULL; the second includes them.

```
SELECT pernr FROM tbl
WHERE pernr <> 123;

DECLARE @input int = 123; 
SELECT pernr FROM tbl
WHERE pernr <> @input;
```

Why is this? What is going on here? I would have thought SQL Server would replace my variable with the value and evaluate these queries identically, but clearly not! I'm running these in SSMS.

Here is a repro script:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF;

CREATE TABLE tbl (pernr INT NULL);
GO

INSERT INTO tbl (pernr)
VALUES (NULL)
    ,(123)
    ,(NULL)
    ,(456);



SELECT pernr FROM tbl
WHERE pernr <> 123;

DECLARE @input int = 123; 
SELECT pernr FROM tbl
WHERE pernr <> @input;
```

Results:

```
-------
456


-------
NULL
NULL
456
```

Comment: Could you include your sample data and table structure? I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: Change to Select count(*) on both.  I suspect you're getting the same results, just in different orders.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti  With the sample data provided, and changing the query to `select count(*)` I get 1 for the first query and 3 for the second.

Comment: @ToomanyAlex I have added sample table structure and data.

Comment: Plus1 for the sample data, but I can't reproduce your results.

Comment: My guess is `@input int` allows null but is not null, so it returns null values as well.

Answer (score 5):

Oh Hai SAP

I guess it's because you have `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF;`

If you have `SET ANSI_NULLS ON;`  you'll find they return the same thing

What does `select sessionproperty('ANSI_NULLS')` return?

Unfortunately this still doesn't explain why a parameterised select returns something different to a non parameterised one

Comment: Yes, that is a good catch. `ANSI_NULLS` was `OFF`; with `ANSI_NULLS ON`, I get the same results from the two queries. I'm still confused about this behavior, however,

Comment: You're right - it explains how we can reproduce it, but it doesn't explain why a parameter does one thing and a constant does another. I'll update your repro script to include this and I suggest you leave the question open

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx): "SET ANSI_NULLS ON affects a comparison only if one of the operands of the comparison is either a variable that is NULL or a literal NULL. If both sides of the comparison are columns or compound expressions, the setting does not affect the comparison." My guess is it treats the variable as a null (or possibly null) even though it isn't because variables are by default null.

Comment: @ZLK that comment is worthy of an answer itself.

Comment: That documentation also says, `a SELECT statement that uses WHERE column_name <> XYZ_value returns all rows that are not XYZ_value and that are not NULL`.  It doesn't say anything about variables affecting the outcome differently.  However, it does say `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF` will generate an error in future versions of SQL Server, and not to use it anymore.  So keep them on and pretend there's nothing wrong...

Comment: I agree I didn't answer it. Just leaving the answer for the interesting comments.